# How to Populate Dropdown List's text and value from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using mysqli to query a database table to obtain the value for a dropdownlist.  However, I also want to retrieve the corresponding description and load that into the option text.  My query is as follows:

```
<?php 
$query=('SELECT restaurantid,location from restaurant');
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
echo '<select name="ddlStore">';
while($row=$mysqli->fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['restaurantid']) . '">';
    '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

How do I revise the above so that the location field is populating in the dropdownlist's option text?

Updated code:

```
<?php 
$query=('SELECT restaurantid,location from restaurant');
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
echo '<select name="ddlStore">';
while($row=$mysqli->fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['restaurantid']) . '">' .
     htmlspecialchars($row['location']) . 
    '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

The above still does not display the locations as dropdownlist option text values.

Update #2:
When viewing the page, the dropdownlist doesn't show the values from the database table.  Using IE Developer Tools, I see a script error in the while statement:

```
Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_array()
```

Is there a more optimal way to structure the mysqli_fetch_array statement?

Comment: @65Fbef05: Just doing my civic duty. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to...

```
echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['restaurantid']) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($row['location']) . '</option>';
```

Comment: Did you mean `</option>` at the end?

Comment: At the end, I'm closing the <option tag in my while statement.  Closing the select tag after the while statement.  Is this the correct approach?

Comment: @Herbert, @SidC - Sorry about that - I did mean to close the `option` tag and not the `select` tag. My mistake. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['restaurantid']) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($row['location']) . '</option>';
```

But what have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

Try this way ([more info here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php))

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query)

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

}
```